# Can vim started with parameter?

Tags: vim

I configured the following statement in vimrc file:

```
autocmd VimLeave * mksession! ./vimsession
```

Is there some means to make vim stated as vim -S vimsession? So when I entered vi, and it executed as vi -S vimsession in background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To automatically restore a persisted session, put this into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
if filereadable('./vimsession')
    source ./vimsession
endif
```

It's probably best to delay this until all plugins have been loaded:

```
if filereadable('./vimsession')
    autocmd VimEnter * source ./vimsession
endif
```

Comment: Reading this answer this is probably what he wants. I misread the question.

Comment: This mean result in a lot of error msg when started. such as "E492: Not an editor command:     `job^
Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Comment: Without knowing your session contents, I can't help much. I've added an alternative to my answer that delays the sourcing, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. It sounds like you want to distinguish whether Vim was started with or without a session.

If you load/save a session, `v:this_session` will hold the path to the session file.

`:help v:this_session`

So if I understood your question correctly, you want something like:

```
autocmd VimLeave *
            \ if exists('v:this_session') && filewritable(v:this_session) |
            \   execute 'mksession!' fnameescape(v:this_session) |
            \ endif
```

On closing Vim it checks if there is a running session and updates it before exiting.